# Presentation of ruby/rails objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When viewing an Active Record object in Rails (ex. Foo.find(1) ) in the console, you get back something like:

```
=> #<Foo id: 1, name: "Far">
```

which shows the model name and each active record field from the database, without showing the same @instance variables, which in this case would be @far=.

How can I get the same representation for regular class objects, which instead return, with name defined as an attr_accessor:

```
=> #<Foo:0x00000102fbf970 @name="Far">
```

The reason why I want this is to be able to see the values for a set of methods on a class, instead of only seeing the attr_accessor (or attr_reader) method variables.

Is there a method that defines what the output of an object is?

Comment: `to_s` is the default output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output in irb is done by calling [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) which in turn calls [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s).  You can override either one of these.  I tend to think of inspect as the debug view, and to_s as the standard user display.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :value

  def to_s
    @value
  end

  def inspect
    "bar: #{@bar}, value: #{@value}"
  end
end
```

YMMV

Comment: Perfect. I added in the class name to the inspect, so it returned the object as I wanted.